# Get all objects of a relation

Tags: django, many-to-many

Here is a simplified version of my Django model:

```
class Lab(Model):
    contact_persons = ManyToManyField('access.CuratorUser', related_name='contact_for')
```

What I want to do is get all the CuratorUser who are at least in the contact_persons relation of one lab.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: What do you mean by get all persons, do you have a model Person for that? Is it related to Lab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for you.

```
CuratorUser.objects.filter(contact_for__isnull=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

This [bit of documentation about making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships) seem to answer that. Seems like you need to call lab.contact_persons.all().

Comment: That only works for one lab. I want all the CuratorUser who are at least in one of the contact_persons ManyToManyField relation.